# Sort order of NULL values in Oracle for all queries in session

Tags: database, oracle

The sort order of `NULL` values in Oracle can be configured for single query using `NULLS FIRST` and `NULLS LAST`. I can't change the way my queries are generated (they are generated by some library), so I'd like to configure that sort order once for all queries in session or for entire database.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you manage to achieve this? I'm struggling with the same problem at the moment...

Comment: I achieved this in service layer when data is fetched from database.

Comment: I doubt that you can configure such a thing, it's like trying to configure order by to be DESC by default. This is in Oracle docs, if I connect to your DB I expect oracle to behave as oracle explains in their DOC so it wont be nice that NULLs is handled differently by one DB or another based in such a parameter.

Comment: Why not use updateable views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot.

Workarounds could be:

- Juggling with your library, like asking for a "NVL(emp_name, 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA')" instead of "emp_name" and then removing the proxy string.
- Wrapping your tables with views that do the same trick with NVL or that pre-orders results with "NULLS FIRST" and not asking your library to re-order fields.